# Word wrapping in unordered list in html

Tags: html, css, html-lists

```
<ul class="notice-ul">
<li class="notice-word-wrap">Delivered,Delivered,Delivered,Delivered,Delivered,Delivered,Delivered,Delivered,Delivered,Delivered,Delivered,Delivered,Delivered,Delivered,Delivered,Delivered,Delivered,Delivered</li>
<li>Delivered</li>
</ul>
```

Above is the my unordered list in html.
css for the above:

```
.notice-ul{
    list-style: none;
}

.notice-ul > li:before { 
 content:"\2713\0020"; 
 } 

.notice-word-wrap{
    display: block; 
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    word-break: break-all;
    word-wrap: break-word; 
    white-space: normal
}
```

The problem I face here is about wrapping of first list where words are not breaking correctly. Attaching the result of above:[Result in UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uLjU.jpg)

Comment: If you add spaces to the words do you get some breaking happening?

Comment: So that's good then?

Comment: @ThomasByy .Yes it is still breaking incorrectly . For eg: Delivered as D in first line and elivered in 2 nd line

Answer (score 0):

Adding spaces after comma (and between words) should make the text flow and line break normally in html.

Comment: Yes it is still breaking incorrectly . For eg: Delivered as D in first line and elivered in 2 nd line

Comment: Try to add spaces and remove this line from the css: word-break: break-all;

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap all the "should not be breaking" parts with **span** tag and style **span** element to be not breakable.

e.g.

```
<li class="notice-word-wrap"><span>Delivered,</span><span>Delivered,</span><span>Delivered,</span><span>Delivered,</span><span>Delivered,</span><span>Delivered,</span><span>Delivered,</span><span>Delivered,</span>Delivered</li>
```

and then in your css

```
span{
       word-break: normal;
    word-wrap: normal; 
}
```

That will prevent the words from breaking, but requires some content decoration.

Answer (score -2):

An unordered list is a list of items that are marked with bold dots (typically small black circles).
Unordered list using  tag

Syntax:

```
<ul>
<li>Coffee</li>
<li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

[For More Click](https://sbrau.blogspot.com/p/html-unordered-list-unordered-list-is.html)